# "You have reached your limit of named versions" when naming a version

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I didn't realize this, but Google Sheets (and I'm guessing Google Docs) as well seems have a limit on the number of *named versions* you can save?

The bigger issue is that I'm not able to find any published documentation about this limit. I did a search for the exact error message as well as other keywords (related to "named version" and limits) and there doesn't appear to be any documentation that points to this limit.

Below is a screenshot of the error I got today when I tried to save a new named version to my Google Sheets.

[image: Google Sheets limit]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What is the question? (So far this looks a feedback that should be directly addressed to Google)

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190843):

- You can add up to 40 named versions per drawing, document, or presentation.
- You can add up to 15 named versions per spreadsheet.